# Is it in good style using html5 data attributes with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, styles

I am using html5 data attributes to store data like target dom and initialize events with jQuery delegation method.
For example,

```
<a href="#" data-target="#target" data-action="/update">edit</a>
```

which means clicking it enables editing of #target and will send updating request to /update through ajax call.

I am wondering whether this is in good style and has some potential problems.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: That's what `data-*` attributes are there for. Of course it's even better if you apply progressive enhancement, i.e. the site still works with JS turned of (depends on the nature of the site of course).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's totally fine to use custom attributes in HTML. I haven't encounter any issues with this approach in any browsers (including IE6)

Answer (score 1):

I use that technique a lot. This is a good approach and makes wonders with jQuery/Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using jQuery $.data() to encode your objects:
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/

You get better data encoding than just encoding it yourself in the HTML5 attribute tag.

Comment: jQuery should pull in your `data-*` attributes using the `.data()` method so you can actually use them both together: http://api.jquery.com/data/#data-html5

Comment: You also might need HTML Shiv depending on which browsers you want to support with HTML5 data attributes: http://code.google.com/p/html5shiv/, many templates like HTML5 Boilerplate and Twitter Bootstrap come with this included

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you don't store a Dom object reference in there creating a circular reference.

But why you shouldn't use it, is simple the HTML should be your view and not your model. I guess if you are not worried about the performance this is kind of feature is acceptable.